# Динамическое отображение выполнения скрипта

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток!
Вопрос вот в чем: есть html-страница. На ней форма отправки данных, подгружающая и парсящая файл csv и подгружающая архив.
В csv хранятся адреса почты. Архив - приложение к письму.
Форма обрабатывается скриптом jQuery (библиотека jQuery Form):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("form").submit(function(){  
    var options = {  
        url: 'sent.php',  
        dataType: 'html',  
        status: $(".result").html('<img src="spinner.gif" width="16" height="16" />'),  
        type: 'POST',  
        success: function(msg){  
            $(".result").append(msg);  
            }  
        };  
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);  
        return false;  
    })  
});
```

Очень хочется, чтобы PHP отдавал, а JS обрабатывал отдаемое, типа: "Файл загружен", "отправка на %email_address%... OK!" и т.д.
Но я понимаю, что JS реагирует на ответ сервера.
Как сделать так, чтобы это было динамично и динамично отображались данные?

Comment: Comet? Погуглите, возможно, это то, что вы хотите.

Comment: а это интересно. Вопрос закрывать не буду пока. Посмотрим к чему придём, может чего нового надумаем. За совет спасибо. Углубился в чтение...

Comment: вот нет резона использовать даже nodejs для такого маленького приложения. Ищем другие варианты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Использовать сокеты (двухстороннее общение). Тогда сервер при выполнении определенного этапа легко сможет сообщить об этом клиенту.
2. `Long polling` ([Пример для php](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/)). Суть метода проста. Отправляем запрос на сервер, если ничего еще не обработано, сервер просто не возвращает ответ (держит соединение открытым - в пхп может реализовываться с помощью `sleep`). Как только что-то произошло, сервер закрывает соединение, отдавая в ответе нужные Вам данные (успешно обработанный этап в вашем случае). Как только клиент получает ответ, он перепосылает запрос, ожидая следующий ответ.

Но тут да, при переоткрытии соединения нет гарантий, что не выполниться несколько этапов за это время - поэтому лог не отправленных статусов лучше хранить.

Answer (score 2):

*Сразу скажу свое мнение - оно того не стоит. Вы потратите кучу времени, столкнетесь с несовместимостью в браузерах и кучей багов. Реализовывать советую только в случае, если это некий тестовый проект и вы делаете это для собственного опыта (нет ограничений во времени и ресурсах:)*

---

Ну а теперь перейдем к практике:

При классическом подходе Сервер может только отвечать на запросы Клиентов (браузеров) и никак иначе. Сам сервер не может инициировать запрос на клиенты. Смиритесь с этим.

Как было сказано выше в комментариях - почитайте про Comet. [Отличная статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/104945/). Тут описаны основные подходы для решения этой задачи.

В случае с пхп взгляните в сторону [PHP WebSocket](http://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/02/php-websocket-chat-application-2-0/)

Стандартным примером в этом случае служит простейший чат. Это как Hello, world! при  изучении нового языка. Переделать такой пример под свои потребности совсем не сложно. Главное уловить суть и вытащить кусок кода который отвечает за ответ с сервера на клиент. Там уже можно передавать что угодно и соответственно обрабатывать скриптами на клиенте.

В свое время, когда мой хостинг не позволял реализовать ничего подобного, то я нашел реализацию, когда при подключении каждому клиенту создается уникальный файл на хостинге, в который и пишется вся инфа, а каждый клиент уже читает инфу со своего файла.
Вообщем говорить тут можно долго и много. Если вы искали стандартное решение в одну строку, то его нет...

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать аякс-запросы, вот общая схема, без подробностей:

1. сперва вешаем событие на кнопку отправки формы
2. в событии делаем аякс-запрос к серверу, в нём в ветке beforeSend включаем показ "данные отправляются", в success (запрос успешен) отрубаем отображение "данные отправляются" и выводим "данные отправлены"; можно чего добавить в error (если произошла ошибка) - по желанию.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("$submit-id").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                //parameters
                beforeSend: function(){},//включили "данные отпраляются"
                success: function(){},//выключили и показали сообщение, что всё хорошо
                error: function(){alert("Ошибка!");}
            });
            return false;//что бы форма не отправилась обычным способом
        });
    });
```

Comment: Похоже, вы не поняли сути вопроса. Будем ждать ещё ответов или курить мануалы

Comment: Ну я понял, что вы хотите, что бы визуально отображалась отправка, или нет? Тогда уточните :)

Comment: я хочу, чтобы в процессе выполнения скрипта ответы от сервера, типа
    echo ('все ок!');  
подгужались в тело страницы.
Возможность так сделать вижу только если php-скрипт заставить писать "логи" из этих ответов, а другим ajax-запросом спрашивать "чего написано в логе". И выводить, скажем выставив setTimeout(check_log(), 1000);

Comment: setTimeout(check_log(), 1000);
stack overflow. Курим дальше

Answer (score 1):

Ну вообще это не правильная архитектура в рамках вебсервиса (а в принближении оно так и есть) пытаться лезть внутрь метода вебсервиса снаружи. Слом идеологии, в следствии чего рождаются всевозможные "хаки".

На мой взгляд правильным решением тут будет следующее:

1.Скрипит (Метод вебсервиса) что то делает, при этом о результатах своей работы он как то репортует через какое-нибудь проектное АПИ.

2.Клиент, инициировавший этот процесс, вешается на событие js Объекта, который или с какой либо периодичностью опрашивает сервер на предмет есть что отрепортуемое (вызывает скрипт который через АПИ запрашивает а кто что отрепортовал) и если есть - то вызывает подписчиков, или иным другим способом об это узнаёт (через флешовые socket например)

В проектном АПИ реализация методов - например тупо через базу. При этом метод из пункта один дополнительно может инициализировать запрос через сокет если клиент это поддерживает.

Как то так :-)

А если вы по факту хотите видеть консольный вывод скрипта, то Вам поможет вариант long pull и отключение буферизации у php.
т.е. определяете iframe с вашим скриптом и то что он будет кидать т.к. без буфера будет отображаться в браузере. Только Вам надо отдавать будет текст, т.к. браузер может ждать завершения тегов например для построения и отображения дом модели.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть в самом скрипте включить буферизацию вывода, а на js ловить ответы от сервера? 
как вариант...

Comment: буферизация в пхп? А смысл? Я вот единственное чего нагуглил, так это сделать через ещё 1 фрейм, в котором выполнять чтение лога и подгружать ява-скриптом в результирующий элемент то, что выдаст пхп.

Comment: Я как понял, у вас при работе скрипта, выполняется некое действие, только по завершении этого действия сервер посылает ответ?

Comment: ну, вообще, ajax с помощью поллинга так и работает, т.е. отлавливает onreadystage=4. И сейчас все именно так